# What does "insert "new ClassType ( )" to complete Expression" mean?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I have the below code which creates an object array and then tries to add an object of the same type.

I get the error "Syntax error, insert "new ClassType ( )" to complete Expression"
on the line

```
vehicles.[index] = nextVehicle;
```

But it seems to me that there's no problem with it. Is the cast from long to int causing some problem?

```
long vehicleSize = getVehicleSize();

Vehicle[] vehicles= new Vehicle[(int)vehicleSize];
Vehicle nextVehicle = null;
int offSet = 0;
int index= 0;
while (offSet < vehicleSize) {
     nextVeh = new Vehicle(db, offSet);
     vehicles.[index] = nextVehicle;
     index++;
     offSet += nextVehicle.getSize();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vehicles.[index] = nextVehicle;
```

should be

```
vehicles[index] = nextVehicle;
```

and

```
nextVeh = new Vehicle(db, offSet);
```

should probably be

```
nextVehicle = new Vehicle(db, offSet);
```